# Cleanest way to remove href from anchor with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, anchor

So,

I am currently removing and adding a class to an anchor with this:

```
$('#link a').removeClass('btn').addClass('scroll');
```

But I also need to remove the href in the '#link a' anchor tag too.

What's the cleanest/neatest way to accomplish it all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/) function

```
 $('#link a').removeClass('btn').addClass('scroll').removeAttr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just going by your description I might try [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) just to be a bit cleaner.

```
$('#link a').toggleClass('btn scroll').removeAttr('href');
```